# Configuring php/MVC on server

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, configuration, server

I have a created a project in HTML/PHP and I am trying to upload everything to the server. I am not that familiar with servers other than the fact that your first page must be an `index.php/htm` file and that everything goes in the `public_html` folder. I am using **MVC(codeigniter)** so adding it to the server doesn't seem so straightforward. I have attached an image of my directories, the first file when viewed locally is the controller class which is `home.php` inside `/application/controllers`. If I just drag everything to the server as is, then I receive a `500 Internal Server Error`. Can anyone help me fix this please?

[image]

Comment: There are lots of different types of servers and they can be configured in lots of different ways. (there's no rule saying `public_html` has to be the starting folder). Find out what kind of server it is and where it stores logs. Look at the logs and that will probably tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a `500 internal server error` is that's it's a generic message.
Try checking:

- File / folder permission *(No files or folders should be set to 777, 755 should be the maximum permissions setting.)*
- If you're using short tags: `short_open_tag=On` in `php.ini`
- Incorrect syntax in `.htaccess file` *(Try removing - test - recreate)*
- check `error.log` for more detailed information.

Hope any of this helps, I'll keep an eye on this topic.

Comment: If you still have some questions regarding this issue you might want to update the question or simply ask a new one. If your question is answered in a satisfied way you may want to accept and or upvote an answer. Good Luck